# Phone Links iPhone SDK - how to return to app

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0, url-link

Is it possible to return to my app once a phone link (`tel:`) has been clicked, and opened using

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:xyz]
```

For example, when the user ends the call?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.  Although if you store your state using `NSUserDefaults` (or other means) you can return to the same point where you left; the user will have to relaunch your app to do this.  This approach is recommended in the Human Interface Guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

No, unfortunately there is no way to achieve this, since clicking a link will always first terminate your app and then start the new one.